# How to get a single variable attached to the URI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't seem to able to acquire a GET variable that is attached to the URI.
The codes are => at the controller

```
...
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
....
$data['ti'] = $this->input->get('hamleno');
this->load->view('anasayfa', $data);
```

The codes are => at the view the link is

```
...
<div class="row"><?php for ($b=0; $b<=(count($hml)-1); $b++) { ?><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/index/hamleno/'.$b.''); ?>"><?php echo $hml[$b]."  "; ?></a> <?php } ?></div>
```

The link is working. I have added the

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

to the config.php file.
However I am not able to get the $ti variable

```
if ($ti){

    $t=$ti;
}else{
    $t = $this->input->post('t');
    if (!$t) $t = 0;
    if( $this->input->post('ileri') ) {
        $t=$t+1;
        if($t>($uz-1)){
            $t=$uz-1;
        }
    } // Forward  button was pressed; 
    if( $this->input->post('geri') ) {
        $t=$t-1;
        if($t<0){
            $t=0;
        }
    } // Back button was pressed;
}
```

Comment: First thing to look at is the link after the php code is run - what does it look like in the browser? I'm not sure what $b is supposed to be but it doesn't look like you're creating a get query in the link. [the URI docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) might help you.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry 43 ... I am thinking of enabling querry_strings for this section. Let's see if this helps... Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how Codeigniter solves the problem =>

```
$get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
        if(isset($get['hamleno'])){
        $data['ti'] = $get['hamleno'];
  }
```

This sends the $b assigned to $hamleno together with all the other stuff in $data.

Thank you all for your kind comments

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with codeigniter, but I've always passed GET variables in this manner:

URL = `www.site.com/folder/webpage.php?myvariable=myvalue`

I would retrieve that value this way:

```
$x = $_GET['myvariable'];
```

or with codeigniter: (I think)

```
$x = $this->input->get('myvariable');
```

Tailored to your example, I would personally de-obfuscate your loop code just a little and instead of switching from PHP to HTML and back in one line, I would simply echo both from PHP like this:
(I also don't exactly understand the url you're using, so here is my approximate)

```
<?php
    for ($b=0; $b<=(count($hml)-1); $b++)
    {
        echo '<a href="',site_url('welcome/index.php?hamleno='.$b),'">',$hml[$b],'  </a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Using very ugly and in many cases dangerous type of variables is not good advice at all. Showing structure of url is not good at all for security reasons.

Comment: He's asking how to retrieve GET variables, not an opinion on how he should pass data or structure his URL.  Of course there are better ways to pass data, but I attempted to answer what he was asking.